# problem with subplot in matlab

Tags: matlab, subplot

I'm trying to display in a subplot two things

1.a segment of a signal on frames-on subplot(211)
2.the values of some formants -on subplot(212)

And I do this for a number of frames.I'm using "pause" for displaying frame by frame.

And here is my problem:

The first subplot is displayed frame by frame,but on my second subplot the frames are added to the previous ones so I can't really succed between the values of the formants.

Can someone help me to have on my second subplot the formants only for the current frame and not to be added to the second frame!

Here is my code:

```
for k=1:Nc

.............

 y_sint=filter(g_p,A_p,g_signal);

  figure(1);
    subplot(211);
   plot(y_sint);

 fm1=0;
  ft1=0;

while((k-1)*N<=(pos+ms))&((pos+ms)<=k*N)
     y1=X(pos:pos+50-1);%calculez coeficientii filtrului folosind metoda lpc
     a1=lpc(y1,ncoeff);
     r1=roots(a1);

      r1=r1(imag(r1)>0.01);
    ffreq=sort(atan2(imag(r1),real(r1))*Fs/(2*pi));%converteste in Hz

     fm1=[fm1 ffreq(3)];

    ft1=[ft1 pos/Fs];




 pos=pos+ms;

end

 subplot(212);

plot(ft1,fm1,'*');

 legend('Formants');

 xlabel('Time (s)');

 ylabel('Frequency (Hz)');

    pause
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's just not refreshing fast enough. Use `drawnow` before the `pause`. That should probably fix it.

Comment: Not that's the problem!!!I'm trying to display also the second subplot in frames but it is just added to the previous frames....I wanna get displayed only the current frame...just like subplot 1

Comment: I used drawnow and is just the same!

Comment: i'm having a hard time understanding you... you mean you want `subplot1` and `subplot2` from the same iteration to be in one figure. instead you're getting `subplot2` in the next figure? i don't see how that can happen from your code here..

Comment: in the same figure! I'm reffering to the frames that I want to be displayed in the second subplot.As you can see in my program I'm analysing everything frame by frame.So at one moment in time in the subplot 1 I have displayed the current frame of the signal and in the second plot the formants for that signal.At the next iteration(which comes after I press pause) in subplot1-I have the next frame of the signal...and here is the problem:in the second subplot I have the current formants but also the previous frames...so the time scale comes smaller and smaller as soon I move to the future frames

Comment: I think you're not waiting long enough for the `while` loop to finish. In your hurry you're pressing a key (thinking it is pause) when actually it's the while loop that is taking time. So when you press a key prematurely, it plots the second subplot, and then goes to the next iteration and plots te first subplot... that's why you see two things from different iterations in your plot. At later iterations, the while might be taking lesser time. Maybe try entering the line `disp('it is ok to press a key now\n')` before the `pause` line and press a key only when that message comes on the screen.